# Google Cardboard VR HUD UI Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

I'm currently creating a google cardboard vr app and I'm running into an issue for the UI. The VR app is set up to be on rails by creating an animation for an empty object that contains the google cardboard camera prefab. I have a world space canvas that has 3 UI objects (backwards, pause, and forward similar to the iphone). In the first case the UI works for pausing (time scale set to 0) as seen in the image below.

[image: Example 1]

However the issue I'm having is having those UI icons show up while in motion. The icons seem to go off in a weird direction have a mind of their own - even though I can track the canvas and know it's in the same position relative to the camera. If I pause in game or in the editor it returns to the correct state in example 1.

[image: example 2]

I have the canvas set to world space and the event camera is the google cardboard camera prefab. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: I am unable to understand your question

Comment: Ok. my issue is that the icons on the canvas do not stay fixed in place like the circle pointer. Instead they drift around the environement.

Comment: canvas is the child of your camera?

Comment: yes the canvas named  "Pause Screen" is a child of the camera.

Comment: obviously if it is child then as you rotate your camera the Canvas will also rotate. This is the problem